# Sass manipulate with @content

Tags: sass

Is it possible to manipulate with `@content` magic variable in SASS?
I would like to replace some stuff in here before output.
Or maybe can I fill some variable with it?

The conclusion is that, I want to make an mixin `@important` that create both versions. Important, and no-important.

**Input**

```
.test {
  @include important {
    color: red;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

**Expected output**

```
.test {
  color: red;
  text-align: left;
}
.test-i {
  color: red !important;
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

Comment: Below is the answer, but now im actually curious what your use case is!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, you can't. **But** I quickly wrote you a `mixin` to make it work. It doesn't accepts multiple `properties` (yet).

**First Note**: I changed the `mixin` it now *does* accept multiple `properties`. Here is the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/MrFuze/pen/mdPmbXv).

**Second Note**: I updated the `mixin` adding multiple properties does *no longer* compile to different classes for each `property`, instead you get two versions, one without the `!important` suffix and one with.

This is the **mixin**:

```
@function return($state) {
  @return if($state == '', '', '-i');
}

@mixin loop($name, $items...) { 
  @each $item in $items / 2 {   
    @each $state in ('', '!important') {
      $suffix: return($state);
      
      .#{$name}#{$suffix} { 
        @for $i from 1 through (length($items) / 2) { 
          #{nth($items, ($i * 2) - 1)}: #{nth($items, ($i * 2))} #{$state};
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is how you **include** it:

```
// @include loop([classname], [property], [value]);

@include loop(whateverClassname, color, red);
```

This is what it **compiles** to:

```
.whateverClassname {
  color: red ;
}

.whateverClassname-i {
  color: red !important;
}
```

This is what it *now* compiles to, when you use multiple properties at once:

```
@include loop(whateverClassname, color, red, background-color, green, display, flex);

.whateverClassname {
  color: red ;
  background-color: green ;
  display: flex ;
}

.whateverClassname-i {
  color: red !important;
  background-color: green !important;
  display: flex !important;
}
```

**Conclusion**: it works as expected and does *no longer* bloat your CSS.

Hope I could help you at least a little ;-)

Comment: I was going to upvote your answer but I'm out of votes for the day. I'll be back tomorrow.

Comment: @DanMullin. Haha, thanks! Didn't know you could run out of upvotes! :'D

Comment: @DanMullin. Neat to know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Simplicius. It's very inspirative!